# PHP Date from Database as Timestamp - add X hours

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, timestamp

I have Googled and I give up, here goes...

I have always had issues dealing with times/timestamps etc, I am trying to pull a date from my database in SQL TIMESTAMP format, this is what I have so far...

```
 $db = $row_rsSearch['created_date'];
 $newdate =  date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', $db));
```

What is wrong with it? I am getting a return of "31/12/1969 20:33:34" when the database is providing... 2014-04-25 02:19:53

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You are getting values '2014-04-25 02:19:53' from database, but at the php code side you are trying to convert your date with '/' convertion. so it will gives you such a way, so just rewrite that line as follows

`$newdate =  date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', $db));`

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right you want to add 3 hours to each date?

Why don't you do it within query?

example:

```
SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 3 HOUR AS created_date FROM `TABLE`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` and `DateTime::add`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2014-04-25 02:19:53');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));

echo $date->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

strtotime takes a timestamp when you use it to calculate a new timestamp.
In your case:

```
$newdate =  date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', strtotime($db)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks!

For other users, this is my completed code (8 hours added on)

```
  $db = $row_rsSearch['created_date'];
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $db);
  $date->add(new DateInterval('PT8H'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this too:

```
$db = $row_rsSearch['created_date'];
$newdate =  date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($db.'+3 hours'));
```